# how to expand GPIO pin for raspberry but still can use pigpio library

Tags: raspbian, gpio, i2c, pigpio

If I want to expand GPIO pin that can use as input/output on raspberry via I2C is whether I can use these pin with pigpio library?

Comment: English may not be your 1st language, but this question makes no sense (if it is a question).

Comment: I think the question is: When I use an I2C port expander like `MCP23017`, can I still use `pigpio` to address those I/O pins?

To my best knowledge, you can't. But I may be wrong here.

Comment: @kwasmich You are correct.  pigpio only directly talks to the GPIO on the expansion header.  Your own software would be needed to talk to the additional GPIO connected to a port expander.  wiringPi offers the ability to use port expander GPIO directly, but only for read and write (i.e. not for PWM or alerts on pin state change).

Comment: thanks  @joan, Since I want expand GPIO pin to can generate PWM on them by pigpio library (may be is 50 GPIO pin). Do you know any method can resolve this problem? thanks joan very much

Comment: thanks @kwasmich.  Exactly, that is everything I want to ask.

Comment: Have you considered a PCA9685 PWM chip (or module).  Commonly sold as servo pulse modules.  That is I2C based and will provide 16 PWM outputs.

Comment: @joan, PCA9685 can generate highest frequency how much?

Comment: @XúcCảm http://www.nxp.com/products/power-management/lighting-driver-and-controller-ics/i2c-led-display-control/16-channel-12-bit-pwm-fm-plus-ic-bus-led-controller:PCA9685

Comment: thanks @joan, "fixed frequency individual PWM controller that operates at a programmable frequency from a typical of 24 Hz to 1526 Hz" it seems only support about 1.526khz that not suitable with my application, I want to frequency about several dozen khz

Comment: @XúcCảm This is really a different question so I'll say no more after this.  You will need to find a similar chip as there is no way you can toggle the GPIO fast enough over the I2C bus.